# 'Add to Home Screen' does not use apple-touch-icon in IOS 5

Tags: ios, web-applications, icons, favicon

We have a web app deployed on iPad that which incorporates the  to specify the app icon on the home screen.  The icon is in the root folder, and just to be sure is named apple-touch-icon.png.  The app icon worke fine on IOS 4.3.3., but is ignored on the devices that have upgraded to IOS 5.  It uses the (ugly) default miniature screenshot image icon.

Works fine on IOS 4, but not on IOS 5.   Any thoughts?

Comment: ThIs may be a change in iOS 5, which changed the way native apps describe their icons. Check the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing password protection On the website... This seems to be the cure.

[Apple touch icon isn't showing up on the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885393/apple-touch-icon-isnt-showing-up-on-the-home-screen)

This would make sense too considering according to Apple's developer documents `apple-touch-icon.png` is supported on iOS 4.2 and later.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4